# When adding an input context for intent in DialogFlow console, why is it added automatically as an output context as well?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working on the DialogFlow console. When i'm trying to add one input context to one of the intent, the same context is added as an output context automatically by default.

Why is it added by default? Can we remove it if not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is added by default because Dialogflow assumes that you will be renewing the lifespan of the context by default. Thus it automatically adds the input context as an output context. If you won't be needing to renew the lifespan of the context feel free to delete it. It is much easier to let a user to delete than to add.